# Helicity conservation during nuclear resonance in Goldhaber Experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrinos, photon-emission, helicity

Within the context of the [Goldhaber Experiment](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldhaber-Experiment). If a polarised photon of [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_%28particle_physics%29) $\pm 1$, is used to excite a $^{152}Sm$ [Samarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium) nucleus to an excited state $^{152}Sm^*$, that then, by spontaneous emission radiates a photon once again, how do we know, that its helicity is equal to the helicity of the photon from before ?